# Wordpress - Display post like loop.php into a page template

Tags: wordpress

I want to make an wordpress portfolio page with 2 languages.
In main language it's fine.
For the English (second) language I added another page (in admin panel) and I made a new template page and inserted the code like in the loop file, but it's not showing the post like in the index (loop) file.

Can I do that in any way?

Practically I need a template page that will loop trough my post.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. Make sure that in your template page you've named the template in the comments at the top. Here is an example from TwentyTen:

```
/**
 * Template Name: One column, no sidebar
 *
 * A custom page template without sidebar.
 *
 * The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
 * from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
```

Then also make sure that when you're editing the page in the admin area, that you have the template you've just defined selected from the "Page Attributes" box.

Hope that helps and let me know if anything is unclear.

If you've already done all of this and it's still not working. You should post the code from your template, so I can take a look.

**UPDATE:**

Try adding `query_posts('post_type=post');` (or whatever arguments you want) at the top of that code, and it should work.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: I did that. I made the page, selected the template page (en) added the loop code and it`s not showing the posts.

Comment: Can you post your code? There could be an error in there that you're missing. Other than that, I don't know what to say. I've definitely done things like this before, so I know it's possible.

Comment: Here is the code used in the page template. http://www.sourcepod.com/elokqa61-4145

Comment: It looks like you're missing the query_posts() function. Try adding that, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me where to place the query_posts() function and how? I`m new to wordpress. You can use http://www.sourcepod.com to show me. Thank you!

Comment: Just put query_posts('post_type=post'); at the very top of the code you sent me, and it should work. Basically, you need to declare what you're querying before you start the loop. I believe this is automatic for post, category, and date type pages, but for custom pages I think you need to let WordPress know that you want to query something.

Comment: Also, if this works for you, I'd appreciate it if you'd select this as the correct answer. Thanks!